# Bluetooth Communication between OSX and iOS

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, bonjour, iobluetooth

I'm working on an application that does does lots of iOS <--> OSX communication. For the most part I have this solved.

I'm using [CocoaPort](https://github.com/agentsim/CocoaPort) to do the communication. Over Wifi this worked nicely and was plenty fast.

I'm using Bonjour to find my server. This required publishing the service with a modded [DNSSDObjects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DNSSDObjects/Introduction/Intro.html)-style net service on iOS. Apparently services published over Bluetooth on OSX cannot be seen by iOS, but the other way round works nicely, except that you need to keep the devices paired and connected.

Now my question is, how can I improve the speed of the Bluetooth connection? I'm getting maybe 100kb/s max and that seems to just stop after about 1 minute even though the connection is still open.

I think I need to use the [AMP/HS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_v3.0_.2B_HS) stuff in Bluetooth 3.0 to get a fast connection. My understanding is this creates an AdHoc wireless network between my devices (MBP retina and iPad3, so should be capable of a decent speed.)

According to Wiki, Bluetooth 4.0 includes the HS spec in Bluetooth 3.0 and according to Bluetooth Explorer, the iPad is 4.0 spec. Is there a way, maybe via [IOBluetooth](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Reference/IOBluetooth/_index.html), to request a high speed connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an engineer @ Apple, this is not currently feasible. The best you can do is Bluetooth Classic, which is probably the speed I'm getting.

If you want this feature, consider opening a feature request at bugreporter.apple.com.